# How to upload an image in mongoose-node app using ckeditor. File will be uploaded to s3

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, mongoose, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor to upload content in mongoose.
I want images to be uploaded along with the content.
I'm storing the images to s3 and mongodb stores the image path in string (when not uploading with ckeditor).

I'm trying to use this module 
https://github.com/mjadobson/ckeditor5-sss-upload

I'm trying this code

build-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  // ...

  plugins: [
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials",
    // ...

    //'@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder/src/uploadadapter',
    //'@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image/src/easyimage',

    "ckeditor5-sss-upload/src/s3upload"

    // ...
  ],

  // ...

  config: {
    toolbar: {
      items: [
        "headings",
        "bold",
        "italic",
        "imageUpload",
        "link",
        "bulletedList",
        "numberedList",
        "blockQuote",
        "undo",
        "redo"
      ]
    }
    // ...
  }
};
```

seminar.js

```
const build_config=require('../build-config');

router.get('/add',ensureAuthenticated,(req,res)=>{
  SeminarGamenameConf.find().then(gameName_list=>{
    SeminarGametypeConf.find().then(gameType_list=>{
      console.log(gameType_list);
      res.render('cms/seminar/add',{
        gameName_list_array:gameName_list,
        gameType_list_array:gameType_list,
        country: countries,
        build_config:build_config
      });
    })
  })
});
```

//add.handlebars

```
<script src="/ckeditor5-build-classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<form action="/cms/seminar/add" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="seminar_detail">Seminar Details</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" id="editor1" name="seminar_detail</textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>
</form>

<script>
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector("#editor"), {
  s3Upload: {
    policyUrl: "http://127.0.0.1/my-upload-endpoint",
    mapUrl: ({ location, bucket, key }) => {
      return location;
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

I'm really confused. I don't know how to upload images to s3 using ckeditor (in between the details).

Please help.
If there is any other method, please reply

Comment: add some code you have tried

Comment: @SaurabhMistry I have edited my part.